# Spring - use different properties file for each bean

Tags: java, spring

Not sure if it's possible since properties namespace is shared, but I was wondering how to make bean properties injection with values from a particular configuration file if there are few beans originating from same class and different only by bean Id.

For example, let's say there's a class Position

```
class Position{
    int id;
    String title;
}
```

And for each position there's a property file with values:

```
Employee.properties
    id=1
    title=Employee


Director.properties
    id=2
    name=Director
```

And XML configuration file looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns=.......>
    <bean id="employeeProp" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:Employee.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="directorProp" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:Director.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employee" class="com.example.title" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="id" value="#{employeeProp.id}"/>
        <property name="title" value="#{employeeProp.title}"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="director" class="com.example.title" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="id" value="#{directorProp.id}"/>
        <property name="title" value="#{directorProp.title}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Obviously that doesn't work because in `#{employeeProp.id}` I'm refering to `id` field of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer object, not of the data it loaded from file. 
`Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer' - maybe not public?`

I thought about to passing configuration as inner bean to constructor but that would unnecessary complicate class' logic.

How else (or If) it's possible to do properties injection based on values in different files without modifying class' logic?

Comment: It should work if you use unique names for the properties like "employee_id" instead of "id" in `Employee.properties`. I just doubt that its anywhere near feasible to do so

Comment: I thought about unique names but that's a bit of an overhead because this is another integrity to be maintained. On a larger scale it would cause unnecessary problems.

Comment: As I see it, you are basically trying to create a database with property files. If that is true, why not use a database?

Comment: The whole point was to use properties only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use `placeholderPrefix` property for refering to exact config placeholder

So the resulting file would look like

```
<beans xmlns=.......>
<bean id="employeeProp" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:Employee.properties"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="employee-"/>
</bean>

<bean id="directorProp" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:Director.properties"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="director-"/>
</bean>

<bean id="employee" class="com.example.title" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="id" value="employee-id}"/>
    <property name="title" value="employee-title}"/>

</bean>

<bean id="director" class="com.example.title" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="id" value="director-id}"/>
    <property name="title" value="directorProp-title}"/>
</bean>
```

Note that I'm not using default value reference notation `${name}` but `name}` because for some reason in case of using prefixes the former notation concatenates '${' to the value